# How to replace each new line in file A with the line at the same position in File B

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

I have two files(File A and File B) that contain same number of lines of content.

File-A:

```
a_line_x
a_line_y

a_line_z

a_line_t
```

File-B:

```
b_line_x
b_line_y
-------------
b_line_z
---##---##---
b_line_t
```

I want to replace newlines in fileA with the lines appearing at the same positions  in fileB (In the example dashed lines) such that:

```
a_line_x
a_line_y
-------------
a_line_z
---##---##---
a_line_t
```

Is it possible to do that with linux commands like sed or awk ?

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** To deal with control M characters in files and remove them before processing try following.

```
awk '
{
  gsub(/\r/,"")
}
FNR==NR{
  if($0!~/[a-zA-Z]+/){
    a[++count]=$0
  }
  next
}
/^$/{
  print a[++i]
  i=i==2?0:i
  next
}
1
'  fileB  fileA
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0!~/[a-zA-Z]+/){
    a[++count]=$0
  }
  next
}
/^$/{
  print a[++i]
  i=i==2?0:i
  next
}
1
'  fileB  fileA
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it did not do what I wanted. As an output I got a file that is same as file A

Comment: @zwlayer, This worked well for me. From troubleshooting perspective could you please check your both files have control M characters in them by running command `cat -v fileA` AND `cat -v fileB` if you found them then remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < fileA > temp && mv temp fileA` lemme know how it goes?

Comment: I ve tried but I got this error : tr: extra operand ‘fileA'
Try 'tr --help' for more information.

Comment: @zwlayer `tr -d '\r' < fileA > temp && mv temp fileA` by running this exact command you mean?

Comment: Sorry, error has gone now but I am still getting same file as the file A at the output

Comment: @zwlayer, please check my EDIT solution and lemme know?

Comment: I've tried edited command as well. It doesn't work for me. Let me know what can I provide to you

Comment: @zwlayer, it worked fine for me, is your actual files are same as shown samples?Also which O.S you are on please do mention it.

Comment: I am using CentOS. Although the file is not exactly the same as above, it is pretty similar. Btw, above command is working fine. Does this tell you anything about the possible problem ?

Comment: @zwlayer, Also this will print output into terminal, is it printing it same as fileA I doubt it? To save it in same fileA will be a work of adding additional command,lemme know.

Comment: @zwlayer, Could you please do lemme know if this code worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Short **`awk`** approach based on [Using **getline** into a Variable from a File](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fFile.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fFile):

```
awk '{ getline r < "file2" }NF == 0{ $0=r }1' file1
```

The output:

```
a_line_x
a_line_y
-------------
a_line_z
---##---##---
a_line_t
```

Comment: @zwlayer, it's not hard to comprehend that `file1` is `fileA` and `file2` is `fileB` (human logic)